# How to append the rest of the command from a variable?

Tags: ksh

In the sample bellow, I would like to print text on the screen and also append this text into file, when the variable `cpstdout` is set to 1. Otherwise only print the text on screen. I need to have the echo part flexible to the `append` variable. Is there any way to correct my code?

```
#!/bin/ksh
cpstdout=1

if [ $cpstdout -eq 1 ]; then
    append="| tee somefile"
else
    append=""
fi

echo "test string" $append
```

Now the result is just like this:

```
./test.sh
test string | tee somefile
```

-no file is created of course

example of print function:

```
print_output(){  
    printf "\t/-------------------------------------------------\\ \n"  
    for i in "$@"; do  
        printf "\t| %-14s %-32s |\n" "$(echo $i | awk -F, '{print $1}')" "$(echo $i | awk -F, '{print $2}')"  
        shift  
    done  
    printf "\t\-------------------------------------------------/\n"  
}
```

Comment: Why not simply put the `echo` inside the `if`, piping it to `tee somefile` in the true branch? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @dkasak I have a function that prints various information. This function takes arguments a processes them in a loop. I think it would be very inefficient evaluating a condition in every command. To be precise, here is  the code I mean (I pasted it in the question since I dont know how to format it here >.< )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your appending command as a function:

```
output_with_append() {
    tee -a somefile <<<"$1"
}
```

Then, in the `if`, set a variable to the appropriate outputting function:

```
if [ $cpstdout -eq 1 ]; then
    output=output_with_append
else
    output=echo
fi
```

Finally, use variable expansion to run the command:

```
$output "test_string"
```

Note that I've used `tee -a` since you said you wanted to append to a file and not overwrite it.

Setting `cpstdout` to `$1` so we can control it through a command-line parameter:

```
cpstdout="$1"
```

A example session then looks like this:

```
$ ./test.sh 1
test_string
$ ./test.sh 1
test_string
$ cat somefile
test_string
test_string
$ ./test.sh 0
test_string
$ cat somefile
test_string
test_string
```

Comment: so all I have to do is to create another separate function that prints output but with tee, and then decide which one to call.
pretty nice acceptable solution, thank you.